# Binary Search in multidimensional dictionary?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, properties, binary-search

So I am building a program in JavaScript and I need to search for values inside of a multidimensional dictionary like this:

```
var myDict = {
  apple: {name: 'apple 1', age: 14},
  bear: {name: 'apple 1', age: 14},
  cup: {name: 'apple 1', age: 14},
  deer: {name: 'apple 1', age: 14},
  dog: {name: 'apple 1', age: 14},
  elephant: {name: 'apple 1', age: 14},
  flower: {name: 'apple 1', age: 14},
  frog: {name: 'apple 1', age: 14},
  gary: {name: 'apple 1', age: 14}
};
var searchValue = 'flower';
```

Originally I was going to implement a linear search algorithm but this dictionary will hold hundreds to thousands of values inside. So imagine the dictionary above^^ has maybe 1200 key-value pairs and the value for each key is another dictionary. Im not sure how to create a searching algorithm for this. Here's the code i have so far for an array:

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
function binarySearch(inputArr, searchVal) {
  var first = 0;
  var final = inputArr.length - 1;
  var middleIndex = parseInt((first + final) / 2);  // i used parse int because if the array is an even number i dont get like 5.5 which will create an infinite loop 
  var middleValue = inputArr[middleIndex];


  while(first < final) {

    // if its the first value/index
    if (searchVal == inputArr[first]) {
      return first;
    }


    // if its the last value/index
    if (searchVal == inputArr[final]) {
      return final;
    }


    // if its the middle value/index
    if (searchVal == middleValue) {
      return middleIndex;
    }


    // if value/index is lower
    if (searchVal < inputArr[middleIndex]) {
      first += 1;
    }


    // if value/index is higher
    if (searchVal > inputArr[middleIndex]) {
      final -= 1;
    }
  }


  return 'value does not exist';
}
binarySearch(lettArr, 7);
```

but i need this searching algorithm to return the index of the matching search value. Any solutions to this problem? If I run:

```
binarySearch(myDict, 'flower');  // outputs undefined
```

This might sound confusing because im unsure on how to explain this but hopefully my code helps. On the bright side if you solve this, you will create a new algorithm. since binary search is for arrays, this one will be for multidimensional dictionaries so thats something to put on a resume. :)

Comment: what is the expected result? hint: use the seach value as key.

Comment: the expected value is the index of the matching search value key

Comment: actually i see no *index* in the object.

Comment: the question is confusing me.. The binary search works on arrays, while you are using a dictionary, which provides you direct access to the element if you know the key... Are you looking for "flower" not as key, but as something else?

Comment: There isn't an index on javascript objects. Also searching for an object in a dictionary based on the key doesn't make sense, because you already have O(1) access to the object with that key. You can just do myDict["flower"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Object.entries()` to convert a JavaScript plain object to an array of array of property name, value pairs corresponding to the properties and values of the object, `Map` object to store the objects by property names of object, `.findIndex()` to get the index of the properties and values within the object converted to array

```
const map = new Map;
const entries = Object.entries(myDict); // 
entries.forEach(([key, prop]) => map.set(key, prop));
let searchValue = "flower";
console.log(map.get(searchValue));
let index = entries.findIndex(([key]) => key === searchValue);
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `searchValue` as key for the object. The key works with brackets as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for the object.

```js
var myDict = {
        apple: { name: 'apple 1', age: 14 },
        bear: { name: 'apple 1', age: 14 },
        cup: { name: 'apple 1', age: 14 },
        deer: { name: 'apple 1', age: 14 },
        dog: { name: 'apple 1', age: 14 },
        elephant: { name: 'apple 1', age: 14 },
        flower: { name: 'apple 1', age: 14 },
        frog: { name: 'apple 1', age: 14 },
        gary: { name: 'apple 1', age: 14 }
    },
    searchValue = 'flower';

console.log(myDict[searchValue]);
```